# Word for the blackness of charred wood, that emphasizes it comes from charring?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is a word to describe the blackness of charred wood called with a word that emphasizes that it comes from charring?

Of course it is technically usually identical to jet-black, but is there a word which also stresses that the color actually comes from charred wood? I would like something like char-black, but this does not seem to be a correct term.

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, you're asking for a name for "black" which suggested "charred wood" - is this correct?

Comment: I'm going with "charcoal". After all it's used in charcoal pencils for sketching, suggests charred wood quite well, and has the added benefit of being black. If that seems to simplistic perhaps "coal black".

Comment: The black nuance of charred wood is called _char_ in English. _There's a lot of char on that bench, Harry; we're gonna have to get some more steel wool._

Comment: I think that's about as close to definitive as it's possible to be on ELU. Seems like a pretty good consensus.

Comment: @randal'thor, Yes you understood my question correct.

Answer (score 3):

How about **charcoal**? It [can be used as an adjective](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/charcoal) meaning "a dark grey colour", probably this kind of grey:

[image: charcoal]

**Coal-black** could also work: it doesn't specifically suggest charred *wood*, but it definitely has connotations of burning.

Comment: Great minds think alike; and apparently so do we.

Answer (score 0):

***[Coal black](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coal-black)*** may suggest the idea:

> - a pure black colour.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Your answer came while I was typing mine, but I didn't look at it - we did come up with "coal black" independently! :-)